# Understanding Spring JPA mapping

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get my head around the Spring data JPA mapping. I have written a simple application, which has a `Person` and `Child` object. Each `Person` can have many `Child` relationships and each `Child` Can have one `Person`

```
import com.example.demo.children.Child;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    //Only used for Spring data JPA so use protected
    protected Person() {}

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "person",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Person[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s', children='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName, children);
    }
}
```

```
import com.example.demo.person.Person;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    protected Child() {}

    public Child(String first, String last) {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Person person;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Child[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s', parent='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName, person);
    }
}
```

in the Main class,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(PersonRepository repository, ChildRepository cRepo) {
    return (args) -> {
        // save a few people
        Person dad = new Person("John", "Jones");
        Child c1 = new Child("Emily", "Jones");
        Child c2 = new Child("Thomas", "Jones");
        List<Child> kids = new ArrayList<>();
        kids.add(c1);
        kids.add(c2);
        dad.setChildren(kids);
        repository.save(dad);

        Person p = repository.findById(1);
        System.out.println(p);

    };
}

}
```

When running the above I get `Person[id=1, firstName='John', lastName='Jones', children='[]']` with an empty List of `Child` objects. If I add

```
        List<Child> children = cRepo.findAll();
        p.setChildren(children);
```

before printing out the `Person` object `System.out.println(p);` then I get `Person[id=1, firstName='John', lastName='Jones', children='[Child[id=2, firstName='Emily', lastName='Jones', parent='null'], Child[id=3, firstName='Thomas', lastName='Jones', parent='null']]']`

So the `Child` are not being saved in the database with the `Person` object.

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong to get this to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `save` successfully cascades from the parent to its associated children (`CascadeType.ALL`), the child objects do **not** have their "dad" (`person`) set when being saved.

And since they are the *owning side* of the association, their relation does not get persisted, thus leaving you with an empty children list upon the next retrieval of the parent person.

To make your code work, just add the proper synchronization of the bidirectional association, e.g. by also calling `c1.setPerson(dad)` on the children.

https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/